# Adding Request Headers to the XmlHttpRequest with Kendo UI Upload control

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm trying to use the code provided by Telerik to add request headers to the XHR, but I'm getting the following error.

"0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: InvalidStateError"

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#file").kendoUpload({
                            multiple: false,
                            async: {
                                saveUrl: "save",
                            },
                            upload: onUpload,

                        });
                    });

function onUpload(e) {
                        var xhr = e.XMLHttpRequest;
                        if (xhr) {
                            xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (e) {
                                if (xhr.readyState == 1 /* OPENED */) {
                                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Foo", "Bar");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Will be undefined if the browser does not support File API

Answer (score 4):

It turned out that Internet Explorer fires readystatechange twice with readyState 1 and the second execution of the handler causes the error. As a workaround for the the current case you could name the executed handler and unbind it after the first execution.

```
function onUpload(e) {
                    var xhr = e.XMLHttpRequest;
                    if (xhr) {
                        xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function onUploadReady(e) {
                            if (xhr.readyState == 1 /* OPENED */) {
                                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Foo", "Bar");
                                xhr.removeEventListener("readystatechange", onUploadReady);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Working Fine Thanks :)